# What is an actor in game development?

Tags: architecture, terminology

I am reading a book about game development ([Game Coding Complete, Fourth Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133776574)) and there is an "Actors" topic which just explains how to use them briefly instead of explaining what it is.

Here's how the book introduces these actors:

> Games are full of objects that bring your world to life. A World War
>   II game might be full of tanks and planes, while a futuristic science
>   fiction game might have robots and starships. Like actors on a stage,
>   these objects are at the heart of the gameplay. It seems fitting that
>   we call them “game actors” because that’s exactly what they are.
>
> A game actor is an object that represents a single entity in your game
>   world. It could be an ammo pickup, a tank, a couch, an NPC, or
>   anything you can think of. In some cases, the world itself might even
>   be an actor. It’s important to define the parameters of game actors
>   and to ensure that they are as flexible and reusable as possible.
>
> There are as many ways for defining a game actor as there are games.
>   Like everything else in computer programming, there is rarely a perfect solution.

I could only understand a very few things: it is an abstraction of everything in the game which can perform actions; it has it's own state; it's behaviour is usually implemented as a state machine. This is it. I am coming with systems programming background to the game development, and so I would like to know in general, what the **actor** is in game development meaning, how to use it, how it is used in general, what problem it solves, how and why. I would like the explanation to be such that a kid could understand.

I have tried to find this information on google but it heads me to another "actors" instead: concurrent programming most of the time or game actors but without a good explanation of it.

Comment: @Philipp I have added the book. Though, there **is** some very brief explanation of `actor` but I am not satisfied with it: it does not bring any historical or practical reasons for invention of actors and what problem it solves, there is just explaining what it can be.

Comment: In Unreal Engine, an `Actor` is actually a class. https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Actors/

Comment: I believe most engines call these "entities" or "game objects"; I've never heard "actor" in this context.

Comment: Your quoted block text is as good an answer to the question of "what is an actor" as you're going to get.

Comment: To make things more confusing, there are also actors in the [Actor Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), which is apparently different.

Comment: Basically it's just a game object.

Comment: OT: I really think the tone of a lot of these books is just awful. It's like they're speaking to a five-year old during fairy tale hour.

Comment: It seems to me the 2nd paragraph in your quoted text explains exactly what an actor is. What is your actual question?

Comment: @TylerH I have asked many little questions in my question here which are not explained by the second paragraph.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Your other questions such as "how to use an actor, and why" are way too broad or opinion-based. The question in your title and in your body, "what is an actor in game development" is answered by your own quote in the question. The answer *you accepted* just repeats what your question says, offering no useful information on top of it. I'm not sure what else your question could cover within the scope of the site.

Comment: @TylerH I still wait for other anwers. I guess I should remove "accepted" mark? The `Balint` did not answer all the questions I have asked.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Yes, a checkmark, or an accepted answer, indicates to people that you've found your answer/solution, and it will prevent others from finding it if they search for questions by 'needs answer' filters. If they see it, they may not post an answer, since one is already accepted.

Answer (score 38):

As you mentioned, an actor can be literally anything; trees, NPCs, buildings, etc. A similar term is "entity". It doesn't need to have a behaviour in the traditional sense, it can be static.

It's just a way to say "an object in the game".

Comment: So this is just a `term` similar to `entity`, okay. I have thought it has also meaning of something more, thought it is bigger abstraction than just a synonym. Could you also tell what should be an actor and what not? What should I operate with to choose this?

Comment: `Actor` is actually a class in Unreal Engine. Well, it was anyway back in version 2. So it might not be just a term depending on which engine you're using.

Comment: This sounds like everything in a game is an actor, which would make that word useless. I would say everything that can change the gamestate is an actor. Then a tree is not an actor if it is only a background image, but if you can chop it down and gain ressources, it is. Menus on the other hand do something, but I would not classify them as actors, they are not part of the game world (mostly, e.g. in the "upgrade completed" flash game the menus are actually part of the game world).

Comment: @syntonym The second paragraph of the quoted text in the question states that anything can be an actor, even couches. Also, not everything is an actor, particles for instance aren't.

Comment: @Bálint interesting, I have thought particles are actors too. They have to tick on update, they have to think (physics), they have a state. Is not it?

Comment: Why not? It's a rather generic term used differently in different engines. Sometimes it's used to make a distinction between static objects and things that have some observable behavior, perhaps driven by AI, or controlled by a player (as you said, people often denote these as "entities"). But an "actor" could simply denote an object that can have a script associated with it. So, in some engines, a scriptable particle system may also be an "actor". I'd guess that the term originates from programmers and is probably related to the notion of a scene (as in "scene graph") with "actors" in it.

Comment: @Bálint It states that a couch *can* be an actor, but not that every couch is one. There must be some difference between "actor couches" and "non-actor couches". I would say an actor needs to be inter*act*ive. If the couch is interactive (sit down to rest, use as a shield/protection, throw it on enemies, tries to eat you, ...), it is an actor, if not it is not an actor.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I would argue that a single particle is not an actor, because you generally do not interact with a single particle. Instead actors may use particles to communicate with the the player (Tank: i'm damaged; ammo pickup: you can pick me up, I'm not static; gas canister: in this area you will get poisoned). But the strict definition of "actor" surely varies from person to person and area to area.

Comment: One challenge that we have is also the fact that different companies make games and many of them are siloed. Unreal, Unity, Frostbite, and whatever else all have similar *concepts* but the vernacular most certainly varies. Any word is only useful in context. As pointed out above, in Unreal, the word Actor means something specific (and that is, "an instance of AActor or a subclass thereof"). If you're creating your own game engine, you get to decide what is called what. "Entity" is another common one but regardless, the functionality that either class contains is decided by the implementation.

Answer (score 14):

By my understanding the term is a side effect of hiring writers to make the stories for games. 
Since they usually come from theater or screen, they are accustomed to the terms `Actor` and `Prop`. 
`Actors` being things that move and play a real role in the game, and `Props` being things like trees, buildings, etc.

From my early days of coding in college, before we were allowed to use an engine like Unity, we had to code our own engine. `Actor` was an abstract base class that had a transform, empty lifecycle functions, and a function called `Act()` which was our version of Unity's `Update()`.

Our main game loop basically followed:

```
for(Actor actor in actors)
{ 
   actor.Act(); 
}
```

Most engines use the Entity concept, so from your reading, just translate `Actor` as `Entity` in your head and you'll be fine.

Comment: +1 I like that it illustrates the fact that you need a name for a base class.

Comment: *By my understanding the term is a side effect of hiring writers to make the stories for games. Since they usually come from theater or screen, they are accustomed to the terms Actor and Prop.* `{{citation needed}}` a term "actor" is generic enough to be used in software design long before people even thought about hiring writers for games (also, it was used in UML etc, things that were used for business development). The dictionary (M-W) says this: `Definition of actor: 1 : one that acts : doer`; I fail to see any theatrical connection here.

Comment: To be fair, I did say by my understanding. You may be right, but people are at least used to the idea of actor and prop in that context, which lends a useful explanation to the Asker.

Comment: I too would say that the term Actor doesn't come from hiring writers but it may come from game developers' early desire to chase Hollywood. :)

Answer (score 1):

Others already gave good answers, but i wanted to add and clarify couple of things.
There are various approaches to architecture and it may seem like Actor is the same as
Entity or GameObject, but there are pretty big differences between them in practice.

- Actor indeed lives in a Scene and acts, "living in a scene" means that it has some positional data attached to it, be it matrix components or a Transform for managing matrices, an object cant have a meaningful position representation in a scene without it.
- Different architectures solve the composition over inheritance problem differently. Unreal4 uses a mix of component model and inheritance with its Actor, as it has a "root" class extending Actor and representing a "thing" in the scene, (look at AStaticMeshActor for example), and a bunch of supporting components. GameObject in unity does not allow extension and is purely a collection of components, which makes it agnostic to its use, which is great for scene graph related problems. Entity in ECS in its purest form, is absolutely agnostic to its use and doesn't have to have any transformation data or behavior, and so its the most "low level" approach. These approaches have deep implications on how you treat your objects in game code.

An example would be skeletal meshes:

- Unreal4 has a skeleton actor, which represents the bones with independent FBoneNode type.
- Unity represents bones by using GameObjects themselves, which allows you to intuitively operate on them (attaching components right in editor for example).
- ECS approaches may use any of the above or not have any bones at all, since performance is the key over there, its most likely the whole animation will be baked into a texture and played on geometry shader.

So to summarize my ramblings:
Traditionally Actors combine data and behavior (and most likely inheritance), and optionally have some form of components attached they are very convenient/intuitive to reason about and to work with as they represent a concrete "thing", GameObject may do exactly the same, however nowadays popularized by Unity approach they will most likely only act as a component container and have no behavior, but components do. And ECS Entity would act as a key id for a group of independent components that can represent anything through data components with no behavior attached (its implemented by systems which act on them).

As with any architecture what approach for your "Actor" you chose is best decided by what fits your game better.